# Stata Data cleaning

Tags: stata

I need some help with Stata data transformation.

I have a survey, where the user can answer with "no response" which has been coded to integer 98. The variables can be of different data types. I need to get the number of "no response"/98 by a user into a separate variable.

I attached the dataset sample:

```
UserN   Q1    Q2       Q3       Q4    Q5          Q6      NewCreatedColumn
            
User1    11 "male"   "12:55pm"  98  "Answer1"   "other"     1
User2    98 "female" "1:00am"   98  "AnswerX"   "Batman"    2
User3    16 "male"   "1:00am"   34  "other"     "superman"  0
User4    98 "female" "1:00am"   98  "other"      "Dog"      2
User5    66 "male"   "1:00am"   98  "Life"       "Cat"      1
```

This would have been fairly easy in python, with each user in the dataframe is a list and you can scan for integer 98 in the list.

Is there an equivalent in Stata?

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDRnF.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the data example, improved below to become reproducible code. See also `help dataex` within Stata (or `search dataex` in an ancient Stata).

```
clear 
input str5 UserN   Q1  str7 (Q2       Q3)   Q4 str8 (Q5 Q6)      NewCreatedColumn
User1    11 "male"   "12:55pm"  98  "Answer1"   "other"     1
User2    98 "female" "1:00am"   98  "AnswerX"   "Batman"    2
User3    16 "male"   "1:00am"   34  "other"     "superman"  0
User4    98 "female" "1:00am"   98  "other"      "Dog"      2
User5    66 "male"   "1:00am"   98  "Life"       "Cat"      1
end 

ds Q* , has(type numeric)
egen wanted = anycount(`r(varlist)'), values(98)
```

For counting the string `foo`, a loop will do it

```
ds Q*, has(type string) 
gen WANTED = 0 
quietly foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    replace WANTED = WANTED + (`v' == "foo")  
}
```